# VirtualBox Nested Virtualization VT-x is not available

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am trying to run a vulnhub Kioptrix machine in VirtualBox, inside of my Kali vm (debian) that is also on VirtualBox. I am receiving this error:

```
VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX). Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0X80004005)
```

I have enabled Nested VT-x/AMD-V in the Kioptrix VM settings. The network is a NAT Network. The VM still wont start up, says it is aborted every time I start it.

I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: host->Kioptrix->Kali? I understand well?
https://www.kicksecure.com/wiki/Nested_Virtualization#:~:text=It%20is%20possible%20to%20run,That%20is%20called%20Nested%20Virtualization.

Comment: Sounds complicated to me. Why not run Kali and Kioptrix as VMs in the same host, connected via Internal Network adapters?